# Qual ferramenta utilizar para o envio de SMS em laravel

Tags: php, laravel, sms

Bom pessoal eu tenho uma aplicação PHP laravel e preciso enviar um SMS para algum clientes porém não sei como implementar esta função , como posso fazer?

Comment: Utilize apis de empresas como comtele e zenvia

Comment: "Como implementar" é diferente de qual "ferramenta utilizar"...

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De uma olhada no [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/sms).

Tem um monte de recursos visando telefonia móvel, como mensagens automáticas, verificações por sms, chamada de voz automática etc...

Ele é compatível com Phyton, Java, C#, Ruby, PHP e javascript, algumas empresas famosas como Coca Cola e Netflix a utilizam.

Answer (score 1):

Colega, você terá que encontrar alguma empresa de **mensageria SMS** (nexmo, zenvia, etc) e contratar o serviço deles. Para fazer a integração com o seu sistema haverá todo o suporte da empresa que vc contratou (parecido com o check-out de um e-commenrce). Pois cada API será implementada de uma forma diferente.

Comment: Obrigado então eu preciso de uma empresa para implementar esse serviço! vlw